# Передача constexpr std::pair в функцию

Tags: c++, c++14

Я могу создать:

```
constexpr auto pair = std::make_pair(1, 2);
```

Но как передать её в функцию? Следующие способы не работают:

```
template<std::pair<int, int> pair>
void foo() {
constexpr int a = pair.first;
}

void foo(const std::pair<int, int>& pair) {
constexpr int a = pair.first;
}
```

Comment: Пометьте как `constexpr` и саму функцию: `constexpr void foo(const std::pair<int, int>& pair) {`

Comment: @Arhad так тоже не работает

Comment: Кстати, что означает «не работает»? Выдаёт ошибку компиляции? Если да, то какую именно?

Comment: @Arhad в первом случае - pair не может быть non-template аргументом шаблона, во втором и вашем - pair не является constexpr

Comment: Во втором случае `pair` не является `constexpr` потому что функция `foo` не является `constexpr`.

Answer (score 2):

Это вас не устроит?

```
constexpr auto p = std::make_pair(1, 2);

constexpr void foo(std::pair<int, int> pr)
{
    int a = pr.first;
}

constexpr void poo(std::pair<int, int> pr)
{
    constexpr int a = p.first;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    foo(p);
    poo(p);
}
```

Просто смотрите - вы хотите *на уровне компиляции* определить значение локальной переменной `a`, которая в общем случае определяется *аргументом функции* времени выполнения. Если вы ее хотите определить через глобальную `consexpt` переменную - это дело другое...

**Update**

Пару вариаций:

```
constexpr auto p = std::make_pair(1, 2);

constexpr auto foo(const std::pair<int, int>&  pr)
{
    int a = pr.first;
    return a;
}

constexpr auto goo(std::pair<int, int>  pr)
{
    int a = pr.first;
    return a;
}

constexpr auto x = foo(p);
constexpr auto y = goo(p);
```

**Update2**

Раз нужен именно шаблон... - https://ideone.com/lgf5Cn (правда, VC++, даже 2017, это еще не научился делать).

```
constexpr auto p = std::make_pair(1, 2);


template<const std::pair<int, int>& pr>
void zoo()
{
    constexpr int a = pr.first;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    zoo<p>();
}
```

Какие еще будут пожелания?

Comment: Но я же могу определить переменную `a` с помощью non-template аргумента шаблона типа `int` без глобальных переменных, почему не могу через `pair.first`?

Comment: @restore, non-type параметр шаблона не может быть типом-классом, чем, собственно, является `pair`.

Comment: @restore, обратите внимание, что во втором примере вы пытались аргумент функции по ссылке (пусть и константной), а Harry делает это по значению. Вывод — `const &` не эквивалентно `constexpr`.

Comment: Вы никак не сможете передать этот non-template аргумент во время выполнения, правда? А вот передать аргумент в `foo` во время выполнения - запросто.

Comment: Кстати, отсутствие `constexpr` у локальной переменной не мешает ее вычислению во время компиляции: `constexpr auto p = std::make_pair(1, 2);

constexpr auto foo(std::pair<int, int> pr)
{
    int a = pr.first;
    return a;
}

constexpr auto x = foo(p);`

Comment: @ixSci то есть я могу передавать 1 `int` при компиляции, но структуру из 2 уже немогу?

Comment: Ну если вы хотите именно через шаблоны - то пуркуа бы и не па? см. https://ideone.com/lgf5Cn

Comment: @restore, можете, просто используйте для этого другие средства. Просто `T`, к примеру. Его можно ограничить, при желании. А вообще, Ваш код мне кажется странным, и мне видится, что Вы от непонимания решаете какую-то задачу не тем образом. Т.е. я бы предложил Вам описать чего Вы хотите в вопросе словами, а не кодом.

Comment: @ixSci Я хочу передать constexpr std::pair, созданную в main, в другую функцию с сохранением её constexpr-ности